# I recently moved to the UK. Should I do something to build a credit history?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-history

As the title says, I recently moved to the UK and obviously I don't have any credit history there but I think it would be a good idea to start building one, especially because sometimes in the (not too near) future I might apply for a mortgage.

I was thinking at opening a credit card (even if I don't need it at the moment) and to use it for some payments, always fully repaying them to avoid fees.
Is that sensible?

Answer (score 6):

If you can, [register to vote](https://www.gov.uk/register-to-vote), as the electoral register is one of the most important things credit agencies check to verify addresses and that you've been around a while. You'll [need to be a British, EU, or Commonwealth citizen](https://www.registertovote.service.gov.uk/register-to-vote/exit/no-franchise) for that.

Whether or not it actually improves your credit history, it's worth getting a credit card with "cashback" that you pay off monthly.

There may be some risk of being rejected for a credit card and hurting your credit record. If your own bank can offer you a credit card that may be the best place to start as they will already know you - this may conflict with finding one that offers cashback.

However I think generally credit card companies will just look at your income and check that you don't have a bad credit history. You may also have a low credit limit to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I've already registered to vote so I just need to go ahead with the credit card application.

Comment: One second don't jump on a credit card application. Because of your non existent credit history, you might be refused. Check with your bank if they can provide you with one.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up auto/direct debit for council taxes, water bills, internet bills etc., Show an active bank account by doing expenditure transactions. The reason is they want to know if that person is disciplined and dedicated to make payments and do not default. There are services from which you can know your credit scores.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's good to know since I already have direct debts set up.